# Error in countdowntimer in android?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I am working on a layout which shows a tab like structure on bottom of the layout. Which I need to show on double tap and then hide it after 5 sec. So I am using this countdown timer:

```
public void timer()
{
     cdt=new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            System.out.println("Timer Working"+millisUntilFinished+"");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            System.out.println("Finished");
            main =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent);

            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)main.getLayoutParams();
            mlp.height=420;

            set_up_views();
            find_module();
            tl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        }
    }.start();

}
```

But I dont know how to stop and restart this timer. How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you not to Use CountDownTimer for this case.

Use [Handler.postDelayed(Runnable runnable, long delay)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

```
public class yourActivity extends Activity
{
     public Handler handler = new Handler();


     ...


     public void hideAfter5Sec()
     {
         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
         {
             View view = findViewById(view_to_hide);
             view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         }, 5000);

     } 
}
```

postDelayed will execute that code after 5Sec.

**EDITED:**

postDelayed will be call only once after 5 Sec through Lopper.loop(). If there are multiple call to hideAfter5Sec() then only you will get multiple call to postDelayed.

If you have multiple call hideAfter5Sec() i dont think there is any wrong because hideAfter5Sec() is just hidding it. so if it one or many your view will be hidden.

If in case you want to hide only in the last call of hideAfter5Sec() use this variant.

```
public class yourActivity extends Activity
{
     public Handler handler = new Handler();
     public long lastHideAfter5Sec = 0L;

     ...


     public void hideAfter5Sec()
     {
         lastHideAfter5Sec = System.currentTimeMillis();
         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
         {
             if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastHideAfter5Sec < 5000) 
                 return;
             View view = findViewById(view_to_hide);
             view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         }, 5000);

     }
```

Comment: But this also keeps on running without any break!! How could I stop and restart from starting?

Comment: See my Edited for explanation